# Re use custom lightning component in different object layout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I'm developing a lightning component which should appear in 3 different object layouts: Account, Opportunity and custom object (which has a lookup to account).

I know I can use the force:hasRecordId and force:hasSObjectName but I wonder if there's a better way to do that.

What is the best way to implement it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take `Object-Agnostic` approach while building this Lightning component. There is a complete [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/build-reusable-lightning-components/steps/prepare-to-be-object-agnostic) on this describing the approach.